# Rails, allowing users to create a form that will be used by other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

Hope someone can help me out. Currently working on a RoR project that needs a strange kind of functionality.

Basically, I have two types of users named User and Researcher. Users can create forms and these forms are stored in the db and filled in by researchers.

I have this basic schema

```
create_table "form_fields", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "form_field_type"
    t.integer  "form_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "forms", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "visit_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "form_category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "researchers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                               :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",   :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "password_salt",                       :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                       :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "researchers", ["email"], :name => "index_researchers_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "researchers", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_researchers_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

  create_table "results", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "form_id"
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.string   "form_field_name"
    t.string   "form_field_value"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                               :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",   :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "password_salt",                       :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                       :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

  create_table "visits", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "visit_order"
    t.integer  "study_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

So, a User creates the forms and form_fields and a researcher then logs in and is provided with this form

```
<% form_for [:researcher, @study, @subject, @visit, @form, Result.new] do |f| %> 

    <% @form.form_fields.each do |form_field| %>

      <%= f.label form_field.name, :index => form_field.id  %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :form_field_name, :value=>form_field.name, :index => form_field.id  %>
      <%= f.text_field :form_field_value, :index => form_field.id  %><br/>
      <%= f.hidden_field :form_id, :value=>@form.id, :index => form_field.id  %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :subject_id, :value=>@subject.id, :index => form_field.id  %>

    <% end %>


  <%= f.submit %>

 <% end %>
```

So the result is stored in the results table and thats that.

I can see myself running into trouble when trying to allow users to set validations on each form_field.

Anybody have any experience with this problem?

Comment: i want to build something like this, what did you find was the best method?

Comment: there is this similar question that can give some other ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942164/rails-3-user-created-custom-forms

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would handle this...

I would have a `User` model that `has_many` `Form` models. Each Form model would have many `FormComponents`. The `FormComponent` model would have fields for what type of form element it is, what kind of validation, default values, etc.

The `Researcher` would be served the form by the `FormController`, which would process the model and display the form based on what `FormComponents` were present. When a `Researcher` completed the form, I would package the response as a `FormResponse` that belongs both to that `Researcher` and the `Form`.

Keep in mind this is just a rough idea of how this idea would play out, but in my opinion a scheme similar to this would be the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually look into this problem more clean way Using Single Table inheritance.

You create a model User and define all the validations and methods common to both researcher and user in the user.rb file.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #all validations code and other logic related to users and researchers
end
```

Create another model researcher.rb like

```
class Researcher < User
   #create validations and logic code specific to researcher
end
```

There will be just one table "users". And there will one extra columns (apart from all email, name, etc..,) that is "type" column.This type column refers to whether the record is researcher or user.

define some method in researcher.rb like

```
def can_fill_form?
  return true
end
```

and make the same method in user.rb like

```
def can_fill_form?
   return false
end
```

By doing this, you just have one table with all users and researchers in it. Things like email, phone, password are all the same and creating a separate type of table is redundant here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer lakshmanan, but I think you may have misunderstood my question which is based on the principal of allowing users to create forms that will be used by other users.