# Rails 3: User Created custom forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am trying to wrap my head around how to allow a user to create custom forms with all the field types. If there is a gem that would be great, but I cannot seem to find one anywhere.

So I have a DB setup like this which:

```
  t.integer :form_id
  t.string :name
  t.string :hint
  t.integer :position
  t.string :field_type
  t.boolean :required
  t.integer :size
  t.boolean :multiple
  t.text :values
  t.timestamps
```

And this is pretty much where I am.   I cant think of how to iterate thru the field_type and return the values, as well as associate them with forms actually being filled out.

Thanks

Comment: Ever come up with a good solution to this?  trying to do the same.

Comment: @noel_g See answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you have some kind of `Form` model, and then some kind of `Field` model, and a `Form has_many :fields`. Correct?

Building the form is than quite straightforward: retrieve the form, iterate over all the fields, and depending on the type, render the correct code. If you use something like [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) or [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) the code is pretty straightforward.

But to make it work, inside your controller you will have to create a dummy object, that has a getter and setter for all fields. You could use a simple hash for this, or OpenStruct (better). While iterating over the fields set the hash with empty or default values.

I think you also want to save the results of a form? I think the easiest way is to use a model like this

```
t.form_id :integer
t.fields_data :text
```

And store the entered data in the text-field in e.g. json or something.
You could also do something like

```
class FormData
  belongs_to :form
end

class FormDataField
  belongs_to :form_data
  belongs_to :form_field
end
```

while this is the cleanest (you can query on values of filled in fields for a certain form), it is maybe too much of an overhead.

Comment: I understand what your saying, and its getting clearer. Would you happen to have a sample MVC or this?  In the form_data what how would i associate it with each form_field?  If you know of any gems or tutorials i would be very appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: kkampen, looks like there's nothing out there. 20 minutes of Googling and this is the best resource on creating custom forms. I wanted to find an open source solution but doesn't look like there's one out there.

Comment: Is there a new solution to this problem since 2010 ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @AnnABlue afaik this is still the way to go. For some project I worked on we had an elaborate version of this, where each field's label could have translations, fields havd different types (short or long text, numbers, images) and we had a similar table to store the entered values. So in short: a `Form` is first a `FormDefinition` which definess `FormFields` and an `EnteredForm` has different `EnteredValues` which correspond to a filled in `FormField`. But afaik no gem or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the process. I found a gem that use the same pattern under the hood. https://github.com/code-mancers/rapidfire

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! It looks really interesting.