# Custom Fields/Forms in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I need to allow the users of my web app to create custom forms.

A user might want to create something like this: age, sex, height, answer1, answer2, ..., answer 10.

Another might want something like: shoe size, weight, answer1, answer2, ..., answer 6.

Each one will have multiple entries (possibly 1000+), they WILL need to be stored in a relational database, most likely MySQL.

What is the best way to implement this? Do I create a table in the database for each one of these forms and store its name to allow future reference to it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3: User Created custom forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942164/rails-3-user-created-custom-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using a relational database, here is one way to accomplish this:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :form_fields
  has_many :form_values
end

class FormField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  has_many :form_values
end

class FormValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form_field
  belongs_to :form
end
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do it.  Document-oriented databases may provide other options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am talking about relational databases. That's the other way I was thinking of, however, there are three problems I can think of with this method: 1) What about field types and how do I enforce them? 2) Is this actually efficient? and 3) What about querying?

Comment: Field types can be either defined statically or via a `FormFieldType` model (you can probably apply some validation magic in the model).  As for efficiency, I suppose it depends on how heavily this is used & the structure of your indexes.  On querying, give me an idea of what you want to accomplish & I'll try and provide an example.

Comment: It's mostly statistical stuff like mean, meidan, mode, correlations, etc.