# Make forms by admin and then show them to users for filling - maybe there is a gem?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is easy, I want to give my admins an ability to build forms. They could choose from text field, radio buttons, etc., then save the form and after that show it to user. User will just fill the form.

So is there any way of how can I make this happen - maybe some gem which can make it easy - or is there the only one way - to develope it by myself?

Comment: Hi, i don't personally know of any gems that do it already, have you looked on rubygems.org? you probably need to search for something like "custom forms". Also this question looks a bit relevant, or at least might give you some ideas... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942164/rails-3-user-created-custom-forms

Comment: Hi Taryn, I have found this yesterday: https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder Now I think about implementing it. I know how to build it, save it to DB, but don't have a clue how to save dynamic data from user input - because of variable number of inputs etc.

Comment: That's the sort of thing that's in the question I linked to (above) it shows how to add multiple fields dynamically to a form. How about you have a go at the bits you know how to do and see what bits are left... then have a go at implementing eg just the ability to create/save one field-type... and see how you go with that. Then once you have that working you'll be able to do all the field types.

Comment: @TarynEast I think that is the good start. Thank you and I will get back as soon as I've implemented it.